# Wordpress URL Problems and Layout

Tags: wordpress, url

Why is that the layout of 2 homepage is different.

When i put `http://localhost/mysite/home/`

the layout looks ok and the blog list is there.. there's no problem here.. 
but when i click home it automatically goes to this url ...

`http://localhost/mysite/`
and the blog post listing is gone ...

I created a page called 'Home' and it's using a custom template... and its set as the 'Front Page' located in SETTINGS >> READING

here's the code for my custom template ...

```
<?php /*
Template Name: List BLog
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php query_posts( $args );  ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <div class="postmetadata"> Posted in:
        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
        |
        <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not sure what's happening. Help..

Comment: Hello, in Home page template what you have? can you put your home page template code also?

Answer (score 0):

In your reading settings you will need to set a custom homepage. By the Looks of the permalink it will be the "Home" Page. When you set this, and then go to `http://localhost/mysite/home/` it will direct you to `http://localhost/mysite/`. `http://localhost/mysite/` will then look the same as `http://localhost/mysite/home/`.